# Git repository: file is not reflecting the latest commit

Tags: git

I have a file named `ABC` in a git repository. The file have some history to be named in time order as 1,2,3,4 and 5. Problem is that the file is showing the content in history 3, while it should be showing the latest commit (5).

I have tested several tools and commands including `fetch/reset`. Even, I have cloned the repository again. I also checked the history in `gitlab` web history. Same problem exists in the `gitlab`. `Git` command line is same. I also checked with `VS Code` and some other IDEs and tools.

What is the problem? And what's the solution?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please try git log and check on which commit HEAD is pointing to

Comment: @jophab (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)

Comment: is the commit same as 5?

Comment: @jophab git status   =>  On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: @jophab I see this problem in Gitlab web interface. I am not sure if the is related to commit tree

Comment: So in GitLab Web, Under Repository -> Commits, Choose master as the branch, check the latest commit. Is it the commit 5?

Comment: @jophab yes it is. Also, everything is pushed.